# Spring reactive Mono:blockOptional conflict with spring actuator

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-actuator

I'm mapping json array response to reactor world but have an issue like:

```
    val responses = configurationClient.getData() // return json array object 
            .flatMap { it.bodyToMono(object : ParameterizedTypeReference<GeneralResponse<Array<ObjectResponse>>>() {}) 
             }
            .map { it.data }
            .blockOptional()  // exception this line 
            .orElse(emptyArray())!!
```

This snipcode doesn't work if I add this property of spring actuator

**management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true**

Netty server cannot start without any exceptions.

But It works when I change to

**management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false**

The Netty started well

Any ideas this issue please?

** Updated **

When I add some timeout value `.blockOptional(Duration.ofSeconds(60)) //60 seconds`

```
    val responses = configurationClient.getData() // return json array object 
            .flatMap { it.bodyToMono(object : ParameterizedTypeReference<GeneralResponse<Array<ObjectResponse>>>() {}) 
             }
            .map { it.data }
            .blockOptional(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .get()
```

I pretty sure conflict somewhere between Mono and Spring actuator **management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true**

```
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:886)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:790)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timeout on blocking read for 60000 MILLISECONDS
    at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingOptionalMonoSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingOptionalMonoSubscriber.java:162)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.blockOptional(Mono.java:1755)
```

**Note**
`configurationClient.getData()` this just a GET request return 200-[{...}]

- Everything work if I use
  **management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=false**

Comment: What is configurationClient? What is the exception you get?

Comment: configurationClient.getData() // return json object 
This will return an array of json object

Answer (score 0):

problem is solved.

Root cause:

It's not a bug of Mono:blockOptional or Spring actuator individually.

This configuration **management.endpoints.enabled-by-default=true** is conflict with existing actuator endpoint configurations

Solution:

Cleanup spring actuator configuration properties to avoid this conflict then Mono:blockOptional work well